# How can multiple threads invoke one same service thread?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, server

**The question**

- The software runs on one DELL server with Linux.
- Language could be C++, JAVA or Python.
- Both thread A and thread B assign tasks to the service thread. When receiving tasks, service thread will put the tasks on its own task queue. When thread is free, it will execute the tasks and return task results to thread A or thread B depending on who sent request.
- Thread A has a higher priority than thread B.

**My thoughts**

- It is very similar to server/client in socket programming. However, since this software runs on one same server, TCPIP does not seem a good solution to me.
- Another thought is to use a common database for this, such as redis. But Redis runs also on TCPIP and I am not sure if this could be a good fit.
- Someone also suggests using a service DLL and both Thread A and Thread B can invoke service DLL directly. However I do not have experiences building DLL simultaneously serving several threads. Is this possible?

My question is: how to achieve this in a suitable way?

[image]

Comment: Semaphore blocking service thread's read-from-queue op.

Comment: A (named) `pipe` or something similar would definitely work. Using a DLL (or rather shared library) doesn't really help here, it's not how service-thread is located in memory that makes it shared between other threads [obviously, it does have to be in the same process' memory to be a thread in the same process, but shared libraries doesn't help here at all], it's how you communicate with that thread that makes it "shared".

Comment: TCP/IP works fine on the same machine.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Could you explain a little bit about pipe? I tries to search for it but not sure what it means. Thanks a lot!